# add a new line to a delimited file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

So I have a file name test.txt inside that file I have about 20 lines of text that are delimited by pipe | 
Example:

```
John|freshman|seatle|math|4|fulltime
Bob|senior|Tacoma|biology|4|part-time
```

I want to make 2 lines for each record after number 4 , example

```
John|freshman|seatle|math|
4|full-time
Bob|senior|Tacoma|biology|
4|part-time
```

Etc..

Comment: Is this `4` always on the same field? What if number `4` is placed as a substring of the field? And what if there are many such numbers in the line, should newline be added to all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/|4|/|\n4|/' file.txt
```

This will replace `|4|` with `|\n4|` (i.e. a vertical bar, a newline, and then `4|`).

Comment: @jimmij Because what if, for example, one of the subjects is "`Spanish 4`"? It's to make sure that the `4` shows up in its own field.

Comment: @jimmij It seems pretty clear: "I want to make 2 lines for each record after number 4"

Answer (score 1):

If your number `4` is place always on 5th field then with `awk` you can add newline it:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}$5="\n"$5' file
John|freshman|seatle|math|
4|fulltime
Bob|senior|Tacoma|biology|
4|part-time
```

Comment: This doesn't verify that the number is a `4`, though, does it?